# Linear models in Statistics

Tags: statistics

I am given a model and I need to write it in the form of $y=X\beta$+$\epsilon$ where $y,\beta ,\epsilon$ are always vectors and $X$ is matrix.  Also $y$ is the response variable, $\epsilon$ is the residual error.

The model is the ‘balanced one-way ANOVA model’ $y_i$$_j$ = $\beta_i$ + $\epsilon_i$$_j$
where $i$ = 1 . . . 3 and $j$ = 1 . . . 2.

Any help on how to write this linear model in the form asked?

Comment: Do you know the definition?

Comment: Which definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Organize all the $y_{ij}$ in a column. For example, $y_{11},y_{12},y_{21},y_{22},y_{31},y_{32}$. Do the same with the $\beta_i$; $\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3$.

Write each equation leaving spaces for the missing $\beta_i$. For example: $$y_{22}=0\beta_1+1\beta_2+0\beta_3+e_{22}$$

The rows of $X$ are the coefficients in front of the $\beta$'s. For example, $0,1,0$ is the $4$-th row.